# Primefaces DataTable+LazyDataModel won't pass setPropertyActionListener in request scope

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, glassfish-4

I have a Primefaces DataTable based on LazyDataModel. I successfully managed to load data in the table but I am not being able to use setPropertyActionListener to show the selected items in a Dialog nor to edit rows. I am using request scope and I noticed this issue seems to be solved in session scope, but I would rather use the former (View scope won't even load data in the table). I already tried to override getRowData and getRowKey methods but they don't even get called. I have none of this issues when I don't use the lazy model approach.

Could this be a injection related issue that I am missing or LazyDataModel won't work outside session scope?

```
public class LazyDataModelBase<T> extends LazyDataModel<T> {

private volatile AbstractFacade<T> facade;

public LazyDataModelBase(AbstractFacade<T> facade) {
    super();
    this.facade = facade;
}

public final AbstractFacade<T> getFacade() {
    return facade;
}

public final void setFacade(AbstractFacade<T> facade) {
    this.facade = facade;
}

@Override
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
    List<T> list = facade.load(first, pageSize,
            sortField, sortOrder, filters);
    if (list == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem.");
    }
    // I am using the following line for debugging:
    // throw new RuntimeException(list.toString());
    setRowCount(facade.count());
    return list;
}
```

}

UserLazyDataModel looks like this

```
public class UserLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModelBase<User> {

    private UserFacade facade;

    public UserLazyDataModel(UserFacade facade) {
        super(facade);
    }

    public List<User> getRowData(String rowKey) {
        return facade.findById(Integer.parseInt(rowKey)); // findById as defined in UserFacade
    }

    ...
```

My backing bean looks like this

```
@Named(value = "userController")
@RequestScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {

    private User current;
    @EJB
private UserFacade ejbFacade;
private LazyDataModelBase<User> items;
private Integer itemId;
private int pageSize = 10;

public UserController() {
    items = new UserLazyDataModel(ejbFacade);
}

public UserFacade getUserFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
}

public void setUserFacade(UserFacade facade) {
    this.ejbFacade = facade;
    //items.setFacade(facade);
}

public User getSelected() {
    if (current == null) {
        this.current = new User();
    }
    return current;
}

public void setSelected(User selected) {
    this.current = selected;
}

public void setSelected(Integer id) {
    this.itemId = id;
    current = ejbFacade.find(id);
}

public Integer getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(Integer id) {
    this.itemId = id;
    current = ejbFacade.findById(id);
}

public int getPageSize() {
    return pageSize;
}

public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
}

private void setDefaultStatus() {
    current.setStatusId(ejbFacade.getDefaultStatus());
}

public String create() {
    current.setDateCreated(new Date());
    if (current.getStatusId() == null) {
        setDefaultStatus();
    }
    current.hashPassword();

    try {
        ejbFacade.create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("User guardado exitosamente");
        return "success-create";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "A persistence error ocurred.");
        return null;
    }
}

public String prepareList() {
    //current = null;
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String prepareCreate() {
    return "create?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String prepareEdit() {
    return "edit";
}

public void onRowSelect() {
    current = ejbFacade.findById(itemId);
}

public void update() {
    try {
        ejbFacade.edit(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("User guardado exitosamente");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "A persistence error ocurred.");
    }
}

public void delete() {
    try {
        ejbFacade.remove(current);
        current = null;
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("role deleted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
    }
}

public LazyDataModelBase<User> getItems() {
    items.setFacade(ejbFacade);
    items.setPageSize(pageSize);
    return items;
}

public void setItems(LazyDataModelBase<User> model) {
    this.items = model;
}
```

}

And this is my view

```
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:commandButton immediate="true" style="margin: 10px 0;" value="Nuevo" icon="ui-icon-plus" action="#{userController.prepareCreate}" ajax="false" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="listForm">
        <br />
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
        <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{userController.items}" rows="#{userController.pageSize}"
                     lazy="true" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{item.userId}" selection="#{userController.selected}"
                     paginator="true" id="itemsTable"  rowsPerPageTemplate="10,30,50">


            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userController.onRowSelect}" update=":listForm:itemDisplay" oncomplete="itemDialog.show()" />

            <p:column headerText="ID" id="userId" sortBy="#{item.userId}" style="width: 10px;">
                #{item.userId}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="First Name" id="first-name" sortBy="#{item.firstName}">
                #{item.firstName}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Last Name" id="last-name" sortBy="#{item.lastName}">
                #{item.lastName}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Email" id="email" sortBy="#{item.email}" filterBy="#{item.email}">
                #{item.email}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="User" id="name" sortBy="#{item.username}">
                #{item.username}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="birthdate" id="birthdate" sortBy="#{item.birthdate}">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.birthdate}" >
                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="role" id="status" sortBy="#{item.statusId.name}">
                #{item.statusId.name}
            </p:column>



            <p:column style="width:32px;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" class="datarow-icons">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" update=":listForm:itemsTable :listForm:confirmDelete"
                                     oncomplete="deleteDialog.show()">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{userController.selected}" />
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" immediate="true" action="#{userController.prepareEdit}" ajax="false">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{userController.selected}" />
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton id="select-button" 
                                     update=":listForm:itemDisplay" 
                                     oncomplete="itemDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search"
                                     title="view" >
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{userController.selected}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:dialog widgetVar="itemDialog" resizable="false"
                  showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" header="Item Detail">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="itemDisplay" style="width: 250px;">
                <h:outputText value="ID: " />
                <h:outputText value="#{userController.selected.userId}" />

                <h:outputText value="Name: " />
                <h:outputText value="#{userController.selected.username}" />

                <h:outputText value="Description: " />
                <h:outputText value="#{userController.selected.firstName}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>
        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDelete" header="Confirm delete" 
                         widgetVar="deleteDialog" severity="alert"
                         showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
                         closable="false"
                         message="¿Realmente desea borrar '#{userController.selected.toString()}' ?">
            <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" 
                             onclick="deleteDialog.hide();" type="button" />
            <p:commandButton id="accept" value="Confirmar" 
                             update=":listForm" 
                             oncomplete="deleteDialog.hide();"
                             action="#{userController.delete}" ajax="false">
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem using PF 4.0. Have you been able to get the setPropertyActionListener working for a lazy DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rowSelect to work by overriding getRowData in my UserLazyDataModel (a subclass of LazyDataModelBase I showed) as follows:

```
@Override
public User getRowData(String rowKey) {
    try {
        return ((UserFacade) getFacade()).findById(Integer.parseInt(rowKey));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And deleting

```
rowkey="#{item.userId}"
```

attribute from the dataTable declaration. I declared a facade in the subclass UserLazyDataModel and this was by default different from parent class LazyDataModelBase (set to null). The solution was to delete this field from the subclass and access parent fiel by means of getFacade method finally casting it to UserFacade.

setPropertyActionListener not working yet.

Comment: setPropertyActionListener and LazyDataModel actually work in View scope but if I have my edits in a different page (a different view) this approach doesn't work.