# Selected rowkey is null when paginating using LazyDataModel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, pagination

I am using PrimeFaces 5.0. I have implemented `LazyDataModel` and I am able to load the rows, however, when I paginate, the `getRowData(String rowKey)` is called but `rowKey` is `null`. It gets the correct key on the first page but is always empty when I paginate to the next page or previous page.

```
<p:dataTable id="sublTableId"
             value="#{submissionListBean.lazyModel}"
             var="selRow"
             selectionMode="single"
             selection="#{submissionListBean.selectedSubmissionListRec}"
             resizableColumns="true"
             paginator="true"
             rows="50"
             paginatorPosition="both"
             paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
             scrollable="true"
             scrollHeight="300px;"
             scrollWidth="100px;"
             frozenColumns="5"
             paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink}"
             lazy="true"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            update=":submissionListForm:thrdListBtn"
            listener="#{submissionListBean.onRowSelect}"/>
```

Note: I found a post which mentioned that we need to remove the `rowkey` in order for the `getRowKey()` to get called automatically - so I have removed that attribute:

Reference: [Primefaces DataTable+LazyDataModel won't pass setPropertyActionListener in request scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713709/primefaces-datatablelazydatamodel-wont-pass-setpropertyactionlistener-in-reque)

Managed Bean:
[Session scoped]

```
public void searchByCriteria() {
    String actionName = "searchByCriteria";
    log.debug("SubmissionListBean:" + actionName);
    try {
        request = getSubmissionListSearchRequestDto();

        // Pagination: Lazy Data Model
        lazyModel = new LazySubmissionListDataModel(userContext, auditService, request);
        displayRecList = lazyModel.getDatasource();
        ....
    }
}
```

LazySubmissionListDataModel.java

```
public class LazySubmissionListDataModel extends LazyDataModel<AuditSubmissionListDto> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 429415464812534969L;
    private List<AuditSubmissionListDto> datasource;
    private AuditSubmissionListDto request;
    private IAuditService auditService;
    private CmUserContext userContext;

    int startPage = 1;
    int totalRowCount;

    public LazySubmissionListDataModel(CmUserContext userContext, IAuditService auditService,
            AuditSubmissionListDto request) {
        this.auditService = auditService;
        this.userContext = userContext;
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public List<AuditSubmissionListDto> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

        datasource = new ArrayList<AuditSubmissionListDto>();

        // Calculate pages for pagination
        if (first == 0) {
            startPage = 1;
        } else {
            startPage = (first / pageSize) + 1;
        }

        // Call the service to get the resultlist
        try {

            datasource = getAuditService().getSubmissionListRecords(userContext, request, pageSize, startPage);

            if ((datasource != null) && (datasource.size() > 0)) {
                totalRowCount = datasource.get(0).getTotalRowsCount().intValue();
            }

            setRowCount(totalRowCount);
            setWrappedData(datasource);

        } catch (BesCmUiException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return datasource;
    }

    @Override
    public AuditSubmissionListDto getRowData(String rowKey) {
        for (AuditSubmissionListDto dto : datasource) {
            if (dto.getSubmissionId().equals(rowKey)) {
                return dto;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public AuditSubmissionListDto getRowData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getRowData();
    }

    @Override
    public String getRowKey(AuditSubmissionListDto dto) {
        return dto.getSubmissionId();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel#isRowAvailable()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isRowAvailable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.isRowAvailable();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel#getRowCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getRowCount();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel#getRowIndex()
     */
    @Override
    public int getRowIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getRowIndex();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel#setRowIndex(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setRowIndex(rowIndex);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel#setWrappedData(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public void setWrappedData(Object list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setWrappedData(list);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel#getPageSize()
     */
    @Override
    public int getPageSize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getPageSize();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel#getWrappedData()
     */
    @Override
    public Object getWrappedData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getWrappedData();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel#setPageSize(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setPageSize(pageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have overridden those all methods in the bean without an absolute need that just unnecessarily makes your code messy. Just get rid of them unless overriding of those methods is absolutely necessary. In this case, you can just do `rowKey="#{selRow.submissionId}"` - an attribute of `<p:dataTable>`. There is no need to explicitly override the `getRowKey()` method in the associated bean.

Comment: The post you linked is quite messy as well. The intention to use `<p:commandButton>`s in conjunction with a `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is completely unspecified. The CRUD operations using a `<p:dataTable>` can be performed/handled in way a which is quite tidy.

Comment: Hi
Thank you very much for the reply. I added the  rowKey="#{selRow.submissionId}" and removed all the overridden methods from LazySubmissionListDataModel.java and retained only getters and setters, still the selected row is null onRowSelect.

Comment: Managed Bean:
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event)
{
  String actionName = ON_ROW_SELECT;
  log.debug("SubmissionListBean:" + actionName);

  try
  {
   AuditSubmissionListDto selectedObj = (AuditSubmissionListDto)event.getObject();

Comment: I do not find that listener method in your backing bean. Do you precisely have a method like `public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {...}` in your backing bean?

Comment: Uh! we were typing at the same time. Do you mean to say that `selectedObj` returns `null`? No obvious symptoms can be found further. Please try looking into the showcase [examples](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml), in case you might miss something obvious.

Comment: Yes, selectedObj is null when I paginate to the next page. I will look again in the examples. Thanks for the feedback., please let me know if you think of any other pointers. Have a great year.

Comment: Here `selection="#{submissionListBean.selectedSubmissionListRec}"`, Does the bean name `submissionListBean` correspond to `LazySubmissionListDataModel` (either by `@ManagedBean` or `@Named`). Is `selectedSubmissionListRec` of type `AuditSubmissionListDto`? Here `value="#{submissionListBean.lazyModel}"`, you should just do `value="#{submissionListBean}"` because you have already overridden the `load()` method. The lazy model should not be explicit.

Comment: I have a Session scoped Managed Bean: SubmissionListBean.java.
Yes selectedSubmissionListRec is of type  AuditSubmissionListDto. I instantiate the LazyDataModel - LazySubmissionListDataModel  in the searchByCriteria() method of the SubmissionListBean as our requirement is show empty table on load and then search for the data. ~Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to figure out the issue, it is the frozenColumn attribute in the .xhtml with sets the rowkey as "". I was able to replicate it with the standard car's example given in Primefaces showcase as well. If anyone is aware if there is a resolution to this, appreciate if you can kindly post.
Thanks!

.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="10" lazy="true"  
paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
{CurrentPageReport}{NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"  
selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" selectionMode="single" 
scrollable="true" frozenColumns="1">
 <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  listener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect}" />
```

Comment: Please file an issue in the PF issuelist

Comment: @Kukeltje, Yes, I have filed and issue in PF issues list: Issue 7850:https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7850&q=lazydatamodel&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary